# How to get original images when using the HDR mode on an iPhone?

Tags: hdr, iphone

I made HDR photos with an iPhone 4S (iOS 7.1.2). In many cases the result is very good; however, I found that in pictures where people are moving, you sometimes see "ghosts".

Is there a way to get the original shots (before they became assembled into one HDR picture), or are they already thrown away ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to make the standard Camera application keep the source photos, that were used for creating the HDR picture.
It can only keep one source photo for each HDR, if enabled in the Photos & Camera Settings, which won't let you re-create a better HDR but at least allows you to save a decent photo in case the HDR turns out disastrous because of ghosts.

Some other apps, however, might offer better options.

Comment: I don't quite understand your answer. What do you mean by "It can only keep one source photo for each HDR"? Isn't there **only one** source photo for each HDR (which can be kept by using the lauren's answer below)?

Comment: @Pacerier HDR is created by combining 3 (or 2?) individual photos taken with different exposure settings, this way we can correctly show very bright and very dark regions in a single picture.

Comment: Hmm, so if it's 2 instead of 3, then it can be said that the iPhone stores source photos?

Answer (score 3):

Go to `Settings` > `Photos & Camera` then find `Keep Normal Photo`, ensure that is on (with the slider green), and it will keep both photos it takes, when details are viewed, a little 'HDR' symbol will appear in one of the top corners of the HDR version

Comment: What do you mean by "details are viewed"? I don't see the HDR symbol.

Comment: @Pacerier sorry, it would be better to say "when photos are viewed". I mean when you go to the camera roll, and you see the next and previous buttons, rather than just the photo full screen